# search bar for tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I need to add a search bar for a table view.Table contain "Names" which is actually stored in inside an object called "patient".I have an array of "patient" objects.
So to setup a search bar to search for names.But how to do it using NSPredicate?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
      static NSString* CellId= @"cell";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId];
     if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellId] ;
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

     ObjPatient = [allPatientDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",ObjPatient.firstName,ObjPatient.lastName];
    return cell;

}
```

Above is the code to show the names on table.
Any suggestions are welcome , Thanks

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/

Comment: Thanks,But I was following the same. The issue is how to use NSPredicate to "name" which is a attribute of object.I have an array of such objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Implement search functionality first take look into below links -

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html

Then make changes in your code as follows -

In your .h file declare array -

```
NSArray *filteredArray;
```

In - (void)viewDidLoad method -

```
filteredArray = allPatientDetails;
```

Then implement UISearchBar delegate method-

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                            predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.firstName contains[c] %@",
                            searchText];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [allPatientDetails filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
   [tableView reloadData];
}
```

and make changes in your existing method -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString* identifier= @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] ;

    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    ObjPatient = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",ObjPatient.firstName,ObjPatient.lastName];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well for nspredicate with custom object can be done like this.

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.firstName contains[c] %@",
                                searchText];


self.searchedMemberNameResults = [self.listedMembers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

firstName is attribute of an object

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find code for searching an item based on the label in the storyboard. It searches dynamically; I've tested this and it's working.

```
    -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"job_id contains[c] %@",searchText];

        searchResultArray = [responceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

        [jobsTable reloadData];
    }
```